# Gaps In Grid Spaces - TKInter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Python 3

I'm using Tkinter and am getting unexpected results. What I'm trying to do is have
different labels, buttons, and entry boxes to better practice my little known Tkinter skills.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

def display_music(event):
    music = favoriteMusician.get()

    outputEntry.delete(0, 'end')

    outputEntry.insert(0, 'Your favorite musician is %s' % music)

def divide(event):
    answer = str(int(num1Entry.get())/int(num2Entry.get()))
    divideEntry.delete(0, 'end')
    divideEntry.insert(0, answer)


root = Tk()

Label(root, text='Who is your favorite musician?').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

favoriteMusician = Entry(root)
favoriteMusician.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)

b1 = Button(root, text='Output:')
b1.bind('<Button-1>', display_music)
b1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

outputEntry = Entry(root)
outputEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

num1Entry = Entry(root)
num1Entry.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

Label(root, text='/').grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

num2Entry = Entry(root)
num2Entry.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)

b2 = Button(root, text='=')
b2.bind('<Button-1>', divide)
b2.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=W)


divideEntry = Entry(root)
divideEntry.grid(row=2, column=4, sticky=W)


root.mainloop()
```

But when I run the code. There are layout issues, I wish everything was aligned, but not everything is, and there are big spaces that I don’t know how to get rid of. Here's how it currently looks:

[image: Screenshot of currently displayed GUI]

I understand this has to do with Tkinter deciding the cell sizes (for `grid()`) based on the size of the existent cells. I have done research, but can't find answers.

Aside from the answer, I would be fine with feedback on how to write better code, and also maybe some resources to learn python for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to get widgets to align in Tkinter when using the `grid()` layout-manager. For two widgets on the same row, the first could be given the  `sticky=E` option and the following one given `sticky=W`. This will shove the two together. I've did that for the widgets in the first two rows.

Another way is to make the entire row a a nested `Frame` that has all the widgets inside it. The layout inside the nested frame is independent of where the containing `Frame` is positioned. I did that for the group of four widgets you have at the end.

Although it has nothing to do with alignment or layout, I also changed the `display_music()` and `divide()` function to be `Button` callbacks (using the `command=xxx` argument they accept) instead making them event-handlers attached to events by `bind()`ing them to a particular widget (which means they'll no longer receive an `event` argument—which you weren't using anyway).

```
from tkinter import *

# Button callbacks (which are NOT event handlers)
def display_music():
    music = favoriteMusician.get()
    outputEntry.delete(0, 'end')
    outputEntry.insert(0, 'Your favorite musician is %s' % music)

def divide():
    answer = str(int(num1Entry.get())/int(num2Entry.get()))
    divideEntry.delete(0, 'end')
    divideEntry.insert(0, answer)


root = Tk()

# Row 0
label1 = Label(root, text='Who is your favorite musician?')
label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)

favoriteMusician = Entry(root)
favoriteMusician.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

# Row 1
b1 = Button(root, text='Output:', command=display_music)
b1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
#b1.bind('<Button-1>', display_music)

outputEntry = Entry(root, width=30)
#outputEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
outputEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

# Row 2
mathFrame = Frame(root)
mathFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=4)

num1Entry = Entry(mathFrame)
num1Entry.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

label2 = Label(mathFrame, text='/')
label2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

num2Entry = Entry(mathFrame)
num2Entry.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)

b2 = Button(mathFrame, text='=', command=divide)
b2.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=W)
#b2.bind('<Button-1>', divide)

divideEntry = Entry(mathFrame)
divideEntry.grid(row=2, column=4, sticky=W)


root.mainloop()
```

Here's what it looks like running:

[image: screenshot of GUI using revised code]

Here's a couple of links to relevant Tkinter articles:

[The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111175154id_/http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) by Fredrik Lundh (author of Tkinter)
[Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/) by John Shipman (New Mexico Tech Computer Center)

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to make sure that the `columnspan` matches in the different cells of the grids. This code should result in the desired output:
    from tkinter import *

```
def display_music(event):
    music = favoriteMusician.get()
    outputEntry.delete(0, 'end')
    outputEntry.insert(0, 'Your favorite musician is %s' % music)

def divide(event):
    answer = str(int(num1Entry.get())/int(num2Entry.get()))
    divideEntry.delete(0, 'end')
    divideEntry.insert(0, answer)


root = Tk()
Label(root, text='Who is your favorite musician?').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

favoriteMusician = Entry(root, width=30)
favoriteMusician.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=5, sticky=W)

b1 = Button(root, text='Output:')
b1.bind('<Button-1>', display_music)
b1.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

outputEntry = Entry(root, width=30)
outputEntry.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky=W)




num1Entry = Entry(root)
num1Entry.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky=W)

Label(root, text='/').grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=1, sticky=W)

num2Entry = Entry(root)
num2Entry.grid(row=2, column=2,columnspan=1, sticky=W)

b2 = Button(root, text='=')
b2.bind('<Button-1>', divide)
b2.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=1, sticky=W)


divideEntry = Entry(root)
divideEntry.grid(row=2, column=4, columnspan=1, sticky=W)


root.mainloop()
```

[image]